# Worken with 3 methods

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array with several numbers

```
int[] array1 = {1,3,4,2};
```

The goal of the exercise is to create 3 methods:

1- method sum()

2- method numberOdd()

3- method average()

Here is my methods:

```
public static int sum(int[] tab){
    int sum_total = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
      sum_total += tab[i];
    }
    return sum_total;
}

public static int numberOdd(int[] tab){
    int n = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
      if(tab[i] % 2 != 0){
        n += tab[i];
      }
    }
    return n;
}



public static float average(int[] tab){
      return (float) sum(tab) / tab.length;

}
```

I would like to retrieve the average of the odds numbers but I have a problem when I call my methods

```
 System.out.println(numberOdd(average(array1)));
```

The error message is : ***"Main.java:35: error: incompatible types: float cannot be converted to int".***

I don't understand how Can I retrieve the average of the odds numbers?

Here is my code here for information => https://repl.it/languages/java

Comment: numberOdd() will not return the number of odd values unless all odd values in the array are +1. As written, a better name for the method would be sumOdds. Then the average of odds would be `sumOdds(tab)/tab.length`

Comment: which line is line 35 of `Main.java`? are you trying to assign the result of the method `average(...)`, which is a `float`, to a variable of type `int` there?

Comment: Note that this method of computing the average will fail if, for example, two or more of the values are greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE/2

Comment: @Jesper "A problem" is here: `System.out.println(numberOdd(average(array1)));` (That is probably the line causing the error)

Comment: `average(array1)` will return a float value which you are passing as an argument to `numberOdd` which will take an int array. What you actually wanted with `numberOdd(average(array1))` ?

Comment: @Ankit Agrawal: yes :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the average of odd numbers, you can simple do this...

```
class Main {

public static int sum(int[] tab){
    int sum_total = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
      sum_total += tab[i];
    }
    return sum_total;
}

public static int numberOdd(int[] tab){
    int n = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
      if(tab[i] % 2 != 0){
        n++;
      }
    }
    return n;
}

public static int sumOdd(int[] tab){
    int n = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
      if(tab[i] % 2 != 0){
        n+=tab[i];
      }
    }
    return n;
}

public static float average(int[] tab){
      return (float) sum(tab) / tab.length;

}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array1 = {1,3,4,2};
    System.out.println(sumOdd(array1)/numberOdd(array1));
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work correctly, because it always prints an `int`, whereas the average will often not be a whole number.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica Simply do `System.out.println(sumOdd(array1)/(numberOdd(array1) * 1.0));`

Answer (score 1):

You are sending it a single number to numberOdd (returned value from average) which asks for a int array 
That's why you're getting the error of float not being converted to int